# Which guns can break the windows on presidential plane?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

Which guns / items can break the windows on presidential plane? I know Glaz can but can anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Glaz's rifle can do it.

From [wiki](https://rainbowsix.fandom.com/wiki/Presidential_Plane):

> The plane's windows are indestructible. The only thing that can penetrate/break them is Glaz's OTs-03. The interaction the OTs-03 has with the window has changed unannounced over multiple patches, where at times if shot enough the window will break or make no hole at all. Currently, the OTs-03 creates holes that Defender and Attackers alike can shoot through.

Also, confirmed in multiple reddit threads, [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/7ttlif/who_can_shoot_through_the_airplane_windows/) for example.

At some point other operators can do it too, but that was unintended and quickly fixed.

Comment: Just thought I should add that the new operator Kali can also shoot through the windows with her Sniper Rifle.

Answer (score -1):

as of now, i believe Glaz cannot shoot through plane windows, but just like Glaz before Kali's primary can fire through windows, this is noticeable when playing a custom game in presidential plane. this is confirmed by https://rainbowsix.fandom.com/wiki/Presidential_Plane

Comment: It says specifically that only Glaz and Kali can shoot through the windows. Why did you think they made it so Glaz couldn’t?